# Docker for windows local registry push error

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Trying to push image to local docker registry ends with `HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`. In registry logs I see `err.detail="filesystem: truncate /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/my-ubuntu/_uploads/25ca078f-2d29-4504-907a-87fa6745c6f6/startedat: permission denied"`

I'm running Docker for windows (Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a), experimental features enabled, OS Windows 10 version 1803.

Steps I'm doing

```
docker run --platform=linux -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
docker pull ubuntu:16.04
docker tag ubuntu:16.04 localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
docker push localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
```

Inspecting registry container it shows that all directories in `/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/my-ubuntu/_uploads` have 777 permissions:
`drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Sep 26 11:36 25ca078f-2d29-4504-907a-87fa6745c6f6`.

Registry is running, both docker ps shows it and when I do Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://localhost:5000/v2/" -Method GET in PowerShell I receive: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0

(If I switch to linux containers pushing to registry just works, problem is when running experimental features and switched to Windows containers)

What can I do to fix it? Why does this happen?

Comment: Is your registry running? Execute docker ps or docker port registry to check that.

Comment: @Light.G registry is running, both docker ps shows it and when I do `Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://localhost:5000/v2/" -Method GET` in PowerShell I receive:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0

Comment: I just try to make your question more specific. So you could make such information added the tail of your question. Since not everyone could notice the details in comments.

Comment: @Grysik do you found a way to fix this?

Comment: @jpsfs Nope, I switched back to linux. Also issue is mentioned here: https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-push-image-to-local-registry/59379 , but it seems that noone can resolve it by now.