# Internal Server Error When Push to Private Docker Registry on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to create a private repository according to this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1263817/How-to-Setup-Our-Own-Private-Docker-Registry

my platform is windows 10 and using docker on desktop.

but i experienced this error when push to my private:

```
>docker push localhost:5000/my-alpine

The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/my-alpine]
a464c54f93a9: Retrying in 1 second
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

---

this is

```
time="2019-06-22T13:57:07.4534462Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="blob unknown" err.detail=sha256:bdf0201b3a056acc4d6062cc88cd8a4ad5979983bfb640f15a145e09ed985f92 err.message="blob unknown to registry" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="localhost:5000" http.request.id=8c71d5fa-41f1-49e4-9cab-2042e2cef0fa http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr="172.30.80.1:1657" http.request.uri="/v2/my-alpine/blobs/sha256:bdf0201b3a056acc4d6062cc88cd8a4ad5979983bfb640f15a145e09ed985f92" http.request.useragent="docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \(windows\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2.6325ms http.response.status=404 http.response.written=157 vars.digest="sha256:bdf0201b3a056acc4d6062cc88cd8a4ad5979983bfb640f15a145e09ed985f92" vars.name=my-alpine
172.30.80.1 - - [22/Jun/2019:13:57:07 +0000] "HEAD /v2/my-alpine/blobs/sha256:bdf0201b3a056acc4d6062cc88cd8a4ad5979983bfb640f15a145e09ed985f92 HTTP/1.1" 404 157 "" "docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \\(windows\\))"
172.30.80.1 - - [22/Jun/2019:13:57:07 +0000] "POST /v2/my-alpine/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 258 "" "docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \\(windows\\))"
time="2019-06-22T13:57:07.8604305Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: truncate /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/my-alpine/_uploads/8e29f389-ebd5-4d6f-ba80-7be8315c6311/startedat: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="localhost:5000" http.request.id=b3de21ad-7b97-4560-8987-84ff62aecb9b http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="172.30.80.1:1660" http.request.uri="/v2/my-alpine/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/18.09.1 go/go1.10.6 git-commit/4c52b90 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.09.1 \(windows\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=100.4211ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=258 vars.name=my-alpine
```

---

is there any opinion to fix that issue?
this is issue observed only when i am in **Windows Container** mode. when i switch to **Linux Container** mode everything is ok!

Comment: Try to restart your docker registry container.

Comment: Also have you tried to push using 127.0.0.1:5000, 0.0.0.0:5000, machine-ip:5000 or hub.docker.local:5000.

Comment: using machine-ip i took: The push refers to repository [machine-ip:5000/my-alpine]
Get https://machine-ip:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Comment: [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517753/docker-for-windows-local-registry-push-error) and not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `insecure-registry` option in docker configuration and restart docker service. And then try `docker push` using `machine-ip:5000`

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry) out.

Comment: i set insecure-registry but and the error changed to Http refused! I switched deamon mode from **windows** to **linux** containers and in linux mode i shared a drive and set volume and every thing was ok! but when using **windows** containers mode i got Http get refused message.

Comment: thank you and i set `insecure-registries` but the Internal Server error occurred again.after hours of try i found that when i switch to **linux mode** everything is ok. so in **windows container** mode my problem is still present! :(

Comment: If he is able to push linux images, then the security setting is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem -- able to push linux images but pushing any windows image would give the same 500: internal server error.  I got this to work by disabling validation, as indicated here:  https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2232

You can pass `-e REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED=true` on the command line to docker run, or add `REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED: 'true'` to the registry->environment section of docker-compose.yaml.

Example:

```
docker run -d -e REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED=true registry:latest
```

or in docker-compose.yaml:

```
registry:
  image: registry:latest
  environment:
    REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a secure registry, you need to login to docker registry with something like this:

`docker login --username=yourusername --email=email@domain.com:5000`

and then you can do

`docker push localhost:5000/my-alpine`

Also, from `gitBash` check if you are getting anything with `curl`

Try:

`curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog`

You may need to use `username:pass` combo with `curl`. Of course, always check to see if you are docker registry container is running or exited.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same 500 error on Windows 11 when pushing a Windows image to a local registry. To resolve, I had to add this setting to my registry's yaml config:

```
validation:
   disabled: true
```

Source: https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2232#issuecomment-297788575